# NestedScrollView with ViewPager and other views doesn't work

Tags: android, android-nestedscrollview

As in the title - my NestedScrollView doesn't work. Changing height to `match_parent` doesn't help.

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/articlePhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/tourPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Thanks in advance for any tips. Full [XML](https://www.paste.org/107046).

Comment: whats the need of android:layout_weight in NestedScrollView and ViewPager. remove both and try

Comment: There's a Linearlayout above NestedScrollView and it is needed.

Comment: Not a good design. You don't want linearlayout inside linearlayout with weights on. But anyway try to make them work separately first.